# How to get base plan id or offer id from Purchases

Tags: android, subscription, billing

queryPurchasesAsync returns a list of user Purchases. But it doesn't tell me actually which base plan was purchased or even which offer. It only has the top-level product ID.
I have multiple base plans with multiple offers within a single product (I assumed that's how they want us to structure our subscriptions to utilise the new billing structure).

I want to tell my users which one they have on their profile page. Also in general, I think it's quite crucial to have that piece of information available....

I want to do it all on the phone side. I don't use the API or real-time developer notifications.

here is my structure

```
Product ID (app-name-pro-membership)
 Base plan 1 (monthly)
 Base plan 1 offer (free trial)
 Base plan 2 (6 months)
 Base plan 2 offer (free trial)
 Base plan 3 (annual)
 Base plan 3 offer (free trial)
```

Btw, my solution in the meantime is to create a separate product altogether for each duration and a separate product for Free Trial for purchase id to tell me exactly what they bought. This is 8 separate products, HA HA, Which is exactly how I did it before migrating to v6.

Just typing this makes me think that it cannot be the end of it. Therefore I'm still hopeful there is a way.

Thanks